# GameplayKitにて、GKComponentを継承したクラス内でentityがnilになる

Tags: swift3

いつもお世話になっております。

以下サイトを参考にGameplayKitを勉強しております。
GKComponentを継承したクラス内のentity?.componentの箇所がnilになってしまいます。
自分の力では解決できそうにない為、教えて頂けると幸いです。
ご教授ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願い致します。

参考サイト
https://github.com/marielin/CocoaBlast/blob/master/CocoaBlast_guide.md

参考コード

```
class PlayerControlComponent: GKComponent {
    /// A convenience property for the entity's sprite component.
    var spriteComponent: SpriteComponent? {
        return entity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponent.self)
    }
...
```

自己解決致しましたので、回答にソースコードを記載せて頂きました。

Comment: あなたのコードをPlayground上で試してみましたが、`GKEntity`に`addComponent`された状態の`GKComponent`(`Visual`)を参照する限り、「nilになってしまう」という症状は観察できません。また`Visual`のイニシャライザの中では、まだどの`GKEntity`にも所属していませんから、`entity`プロパティは`nil`ですので、それを通じてアクセスされる`damage`プロパティが`nil`なのは当然ということになります。インスタンスの生成や参照の仕方、あるいは確認のタイミングに問題があるように思われます。「nilになってしまう」をPlayground上で確認できるようなコードをご質問に追記していただけますでしょうか。

Comment: いつもご回答ありがとうございます。ソースコードを「別の回答を追加」にて記載させて頂きました（このコメントにコードを記載しましたら文字数オーバーした為）。ご覧頂けましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

簡易なソースコードで試したところ意図した動作で動いていることを確認しました。
そのコードを記載致します。
いろいろアドバイス頂きありがとうございます。

```
class GameScene {

    init() {
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func didMove() {
        let entityManager = EntityManager()
    }
}

class EntityManager {

    init() {
        let player: GKEntity = Player()

        if let visual = player.component(ofType: Visual.self) {
            print(visual.callDamage())  // "hit"
        }
    }
}

class Player: GKEntity {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        addComponent(Visual())
        addComponent(Damage())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class Visual: GKComponent {

    // 自身のエンティティにおいてコンポーネントから他のコンポーネントを呼び出す便利なプロパティ
    var damage: Damage? {
        return entity?.component(ofType: Damage.self)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func callDamage() -> String {
        return (self.damage?.message())!
    }
}

class Damage: GKComponent {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func message() -> String {
        return "hit"
    }
}

let i = GameScene()
i.didMove()
```